# Command verbatiminput error with Keyboard character used is undefined

Tags: verbatim

[This is the probit.txt file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_HQiYAKcBAFPv07IxXzYc9ATscxbM5XR/view?usp=sharing)

I use the `verbatim` package to insert some text file. In particular using the command, `\verbatiminput{probit.txt}`. But there are some characters in the text file that cause the error :

> Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
>   (inputenc) in inputencoding `utf8'

I detect that the problem is caused by these symbols in the txt file:

> **‘ ’**

How can I bypass these errors and use the `\verbatiminput{probit.txt}` command to insert `verbatim` environment.

*(Because I have so many text files, I don't want to remove the symbol from each of them or use the `\begin{verbatim} \end{verbatim}` because it would be very time consuming to copy-paste all the text files. )*

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx} 


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{First section}

Your text goes here.

\verbatiminput{probit.txt}


More text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Can you please add an excerpt of the `probit.txt` file so that it produces an error on your system? Also, what TeX distribution and operating system are you using?

Comment: @egreg : I uploaded the file. I use Texworks in Wins 10.

Comment: For changing the encoding of many files at once in Windows see, e.g., https://superuser.com/questions/27060/batch-convert-files-for-encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shown file `probit.txt` is encoded in ansi, not utf8. Therefore you get the error message, because your tex file wants utf8 encoding based on `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}`.

After opening your linked file with notepad++ you can see your encoding marked with the red circle:

[image]

Change the encoding of file `probit.txt` to utf8 and you get rid of the errors.

Comment: Thank you for such thorough explanation. Works like a charm!